# Inserting node at the end of LinkList in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I don't have any problems to insert `nodes` in the middle or at the beginning of a `LinkedList`. However, at the end is different. When I try to print the values, it gives me the address:[image]

Now, here is how I build the `LinkedList`:

```
employeeData ed[4];

node *head = NULL, *list = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    fscanf(file, "%d %s %d %d %lf", &ed[i].EMP_ID, ed[i].name, &ed[i].dept, &ed[i].rank, &ed[i].salary);

head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

head->employee = ed[0];
head->next = NULL;

list = head;

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){

    node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    ptr->employee = ed[i];
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head->next = ptr;

    head = head->next;
}
```

Here is how I add nodes to it:

```
node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)), *temptr = list, *endNode = list;

newNode->employee.EMP_ID = id;
strcpy(newNode->employee.name, name);
newNode->employee.dept = dept;
newNode->employee.rank = rank;
newNode->employee.salary = salary;
newNode->next = NULL;

while (endNode->next != NULL) endNode = endNode->next;

if (id < temptr->employee.EMP_ID){
    newNode->next = list;
    list = newNode;
}
else if (id > endNode->employee.EMP_ID){
    endNode->next = newNode;
}
else{

    while ((temptr->next != NULL) && (temptr->next->employee.EMP_ID < newNode->employee.EMP_ID))
        temptr = temptr->next;

    newNode->next = temptr->next;

    temptr->next = newNode;
}
```

When I try to remove the value, It will remove it. However, it does not display the value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `i < 5`, `ed[i]`..`ed[4]`Incorrect data.

Comment: I don't know why. But, when I choose 4 instead of 5, it does not display the last record (20, BoyBlue...). But, the problem is definitely there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BLUEPIXY stated, the problem was during the building.

the index needed to be in 4 `for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)`

And also, I changed how I printed the list.

from

```
while (temp->next != NULL){
    printf("");
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

to

```
while (temp != NULL){
    printf("");
    temp = temp->next;
}
```